# Print a html page using django

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to print a HTML page using django.
I mean that if an user wants to print a webpage with printer when press print button 《print button is a HTML button with tag 》 server automatically print that webpage on a paper.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print the html page with a print button like this (see [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp)):

```html
<button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button>
```

**OR**

You can [generate a pdf version of the view with django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/outputting-pdf/).